# using ruby extension, rubocop with Visual Studio Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, visual-studio-code, rubocop

trying to use the VS code extension Ruby. And having it format files on save with rubocop.

But when saving i'm getting the error env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory

```
  "ruby.useLanguageServer": true,
  "ruby.lint": {
    "rubocop": {
      "useBundler": true
    }
  },
  "ruby.rubocop.executePath": "/Users/jac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/"
```

These are the ruby settings in settings.json.

I searched around and was suggested to change bin, to wrappers,
and after finding out i didn't have any wrappers for some reason, i rebuild them, and attempted it, But got this long error
[cannot load such file -- rubocop-rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogFSf.png)

I'm new to all ruby related stuff, so might be something obvious i'm missing.

Comment: Try `gem install rubocop-rails` from the console?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the formatting and linting working. After disabling "use bundler"
and having rubocop installed globally with gem install rubocop